# django evaluate string that spans relationships on object

Tags: django

Similar to [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), I have an object that I want to dynamically evaluate a string that specifies a related object's property.

For example on a `question_response` object I have I want to evaluate `survey_response__responder__first_name`.

In a list I'm specifying attributes I want to be looked up on an object and exported to csv. e.g. ['title', 'question_response_id']. So basically my script is getting a list of objects, and then grabbing all the attributes specified and putting the data into a csv. (Actually it's django tablib that I'm working with).

I want to be able to specify not just attributes on that object, but attributes on relationships. I already have the object, so I'm not starting with an object manager. I'm trying to figure out if I can take that attribute string that spans relationships and evaluate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The django admin app is able to do this already so I dug around the source and in [`django.contrib.admin.utils.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/util.py) there are lots of utility functions that parse a lookup string to its fields in order to chain them as part of filters in a query set. Of particular interest is [`get_field_from_path`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/util.py#L418):

```
def get_fields_from_path(model, path):
    """ Return list of Fields given path relative to model.

    e.g. (ModelX, "user__groups__name") -> [
        <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey object at 0x...>,
        <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField object at 0x...>,
        <django.db.models.fields.CharField object at 0x...>,
    ]
    """
    pieces = path.split(LOOKUP_SEP)
    fields = []
    for piece in pieces:
        if fields:
            parent = get_model_from_relation(fields[-1])
        else:
            parent = model
        fields.append(parent._meta.get_field_by_name(piece)[0])
    return fields
```

Combine this with the other functions from `utils.py` and you have your solution.

Comment: Ahh interesting. Very cool. Going to have to switch this to the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, not directly.  However, if you're willing to do another database hit, it can be done easily:

```
fields = [
    'survey_response__responder__first_name',
    'survey_response__responder__last_name',
]
known_objects = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
pks = [obj.pk for obj in known_objects]

SomeModel.objects.filter(pk__in = pks).values_list(*fields)
```

*Aside, doing one query for all this data is probably the right way to go; `obj1.survey_response.responder.first_name` is going to do 2 queries:  one for response, then another for responder, and more if you're looping over `obj2`, `obj3`, etc, if you didn't already `select_related()` on them.*

Comment: Standby. Clarifying above.

Comment: This is an admin task that only occurs once and awhile, so the former solution will probably be fine. I would rather not hack up admin tablib too much, but don't want to specify functions instead of strings for every related field.

Comment: The problem with your suggestion after the solution is that I can't do that dynamically. I can't evaluate getattr(obj, 'survey_response__responder'). I would have to split on the `__` I guess to do that. Hmmm.

Answer (score 1):

FYI I found another solution similar to @Burhan's suggestion, but not leveraging the `utils.py` functions.

Found on this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2868/

Namely the `prep_field` method:

```
def prep_field(obj, field):
    """ Returns the field as a unicode string. If the field is a callable, it
    attempts to call it first, without arguments.
    """
    if '__' in field:
        bits = field.split('__')
        field = bits.pop()

        for bit in bits:
            obj = getattr(obj, bit, None)

            if obj is None:
                return ""

    attr = getattr(obj, field)
    output = attr() if callable(attr) else attr
    return unicode(output).encode('utf-8') if output else ""
```

Comment: By the way, this seems to be a copy of [`lookup_field`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/util.py#L244)

Comment: I know this doesn't matter for your use case, but I'll note for others who might not realize:  Each call to `getattr` in the loop will load another model, so each iteration means a database hit unless they were previously loaded. ([more information and examples here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related))

Comment: Yeah for sure. You'll want this to be a celery task or something if you are doing anything remotely in depth.